# Python: Cannot read returned values from functions

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I am working on an Fall Detection System. I wrote the Arduino Code and connected to Firebase. So now I have two variables that get 1 or 0 status, and I created a mobile application to receive an automatic push notification whenever the system detects a fall through **Firebase+Pusher**. I wrote this Python code with PyCharm and I used the stream function to read live data from Firebase and send automatic notifications. The code was working for the variable "Fall_Detection_Status" and I was able to receive push notifications normally with every fall detection. But I tried to modify the code to read data from another variable "**Fall_Detection_Status1**" and I want my code now to send the notification if both variables are giving 1's. I came up with this code but it seems that the last if statement is not working because I am not able to receive notifications and also print(response['publishId']) at the end of the if statement is not showing any result.

So what is wrong?

```
import pyrebase

from pusher_push_notifications import PushNotifications
config = {
    'apiKey': "***********************************",
    'authDomain': "arfduinopushnotification.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://arduinopushnotification.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "arduinopushnotification",
    'storageBucket': "arduinopushnotification.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "************"
  }

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
pn_client = PushNotifications(
    instance_id='*****************************',
    secret_key='**************************',
)

value = 0
value1 = 0


def stream_handler(message):
    global value
    print(message)
    if message['data'] is 1:
        value = message['data']
    return value


def stream_handler1(message):
    global value1
    print(message)
    if message['data'] is 1:
        value1 = message['data']
    return value1


if value == 1 & value1 == 1:
        response = pn_client.publish(
            interests=['hello'],
            publish_body={
                'apns': {
                    'aps': {
                        'alert': 'Hello!',
                    },
                },
                'fcm': {
                 'notification': {
                    'title': 'Notification',
                    'body': 'Fall Detected !!',
                    },
                },
            },
        )
        print(response['publishId'])


my_stream = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status").stream(stream_handler)
my_stream1 = db.child("Fall_Detection_Status1").stream(stream_handler1)
```

Comment: You dont need to return the value if you have made it global.. try taking out the return values.. it may help

Comment: Still not working

Comment: maybe the message is a `str` .. try `value = int(message['data'])`

Comment: also maybe try usin `and` instead of `&` in the `if` statement

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: what does `print(type(message))` return? what is the datatype?

Comment: {'path': '/', 'data': 0, 'event': 'put'}
or
{'path': '/', 'data': 1, 'event': 'put'}

Comment: the system should send notification when message data is 1 in stream_handler and stream_handler1

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator '&' to combine the results of the two tests. In Python, '&' is the bitwise and operator! I believe you want the logical version which is 'and'.

Secondly, assuming the stream_handler/1 calls are run by your last two statements, those two statements are AFTER the place where you test the values in the if statement. Move those line above the if block.